# Update destination property in Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have 2 properties in the `Source` class and that needs to be combined and updated in the `Destination` class.

I tried like below and I had the destination namespace as the value and not the actual value.

//Code

```
    CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => new Destination { Name = y.FirstName + y.LastName }));
```

I need the `FirstName` & `LastName` property from the source to be combined and set to `Name` property in Destiantion class.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `ForMember` call, `x` is of type `Destination` and `y` is of type `Source` (that's why they usually are named `dst` and `src`). The destination member is provided by the first expression (`x.Name`), so inside `MapFrom` you just need to provide the source expression to be assigned to that member:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName + src.LastName));
```